# Different measures having the equal integrals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

In reading my measure theory book I found the following interesting problem, which I honestly have no idea how to even attempt:

Suppose $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ are $\sigma$ -algebras on a set $X$ and $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathcal{T} .$ Suppose $\mu_{1}$ is a measure on $(X, \mathcal{S}), \mu_{2}$ is a measure on $(X, \mathcal{T}),$ and $\mu_{1}(E)=\mu_{2}(E)$ for all $E \in \mathcal{S} .$ Prove that if $f: X \rightarrow[0, \infty]$ is $\mathcal{S}$ -measurable, then $\int f d \mu_{1}=\int f d \mu_{2}$

Does anyone have any suggestions how to go about this proof?

Comment: Go back to the definition and approximate.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I am sorry but could I get a bit more clarification?

Comment: A standard technique in measure theory is to prove something for indicator functions, then simple functions and then all measurable functions. You know the integrals are equal on indicator functions.

Comment: Look at simple functions, you’ll find that their integrals are the same for the two measures.  Then, take limits.